# Is it possible to use a frames marker name and append it to the file name upon export?

Tags: rendering, animation

I am batch rendering files and it would really help me if I could add the marker name of the frame being rendered to the name of the output file. So for example my marker is called 'front_view' and the file name for that rendered frame would be 'front_view_objectname.png' or at least 'front_view.png','back_view.png' etc.

I searched online and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't supported, however there are some options you could try instead.

- Stamp the marker name into the file and read the marker name back out later. (JPEG, EXR, PNG support writing stamp data into the file)
- Write a pre-render handler to impliment this with a python script, so before rendering, change the name based on the marker *(I didn't check this works, only some settings can be changed while rendering)*. (See: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.app.handlers.html)
- Render marker ranges - See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15373/55 triggered by a python script.